# Timeout not working with IO on Windows

Tags: ruby

The following code does not time out in Ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]:

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout.timeout(1) { gets }
```

I expected it to work since Ruby 1.9 uses native threads. Is this intended (or documented) behavior or a bug?  In the [documentation of `Timeout`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) there is no mention of any restriction wrt. blocking IO or whatever.

(According to the comments, this seems to be an issue of the Windows version only.)

Comment: Works well here with 1.9.3p125 [x86_64-linux] (I get a Timeout::Error after one second.)

Comment: Same here, works with `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of the current Ruby 1.9.3 for Windows which had already been fixed in trunk. The fix has been backported into 1.9.3: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6661.