# Ruby 1.8 hangs making http request

Tags: ruby

I have the next configuration:

```
Net::HTTP.ssl_context_accessor 'ssl_version'
@http = Net::HTTP.new(@url.host, 443)
@http.ssl_version = :SSLv2
@http.use_ssl = true
@http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

@http.set_debug_output $stderr
@http.open_timeout = 10
@http.read_timeout = 10
```

And then I use the @http object to make a request_get this way:

```
path = "/login.cgi?username=#{@url.user}&password=#{@url.password}"
debug("Making request #{@http.address}")
response = @http.request_get(path)
debug("#{response.body}")
@cookie = response.get_fields('set-cookie').split('; ')[0]

Puppet.debug('Cookie got!')
```

The server is supposed to return me a cookie, but the only output I get from the debug is

```
Debug: Making request server.com
opening connection to server.com...
opened
```

And it hangs there forever (not even raising timeout).

I'm very new to ruby, and this code has been retrieved from other stackoverflow questions, and was suppose to work.

I've been searching for google, but haven't found anything similar, any idea?

Comment: 1.8 is quite aged. At least on Windows, there were some issues with timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049009/timeout-not-working-with-io-on-windows.

Comment: Are you sure that the server requires the very old and insecure SSL 2.0 protocol which you explicitly set? I doubt it, most systems don't even have support for this version any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SSL version to SSLv3 and the request_get method by post solved the problem.